# How to write an NES function that also takes character input?

Tags: r, eval, lazy-evaluation

I´m working on a R package that takes strings as function arguments. Now I want to use non-standard evaluation to allow for non-string input. Also, to keep the backwards compatibility, I´d like to keep the possibility for the functions to take strings.

Hadley gives an [example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html) with the subset function and suggests that every NES function should be accompanied by a standard evaluation function.

```
library(lazyeval)
# standard evaluation
subset2_ <- function(df, condition) {
    r <- lazy_eval(condition, df)
    r <- r & !is.na(r)
    df[r, , drop = FALSE]
} 

subset2_(mtcars, lazy(mpg > 31))


# NES can be written easily afterwards

subset2 <- function(df, condition) {
    subset2_(df, lazy(condition))
}
```

While the SE function now also takes quoted input,

```
subset2_(mtcars, "mpg > 31")
```

the NSE function throws an error:

```
subset2(mtcars, "mpg > 31")
```

But I want the user to have the same function (the NSE function) for both quoted as well as unquoted arguments.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would add another argument to differentiate the 2 cases. i.e `with=FALSE` for character case à la `data.table`  manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NSE function takes *NSE* input. That’s the point of this pattern, isn’t it?

```
subset2(mtcars, mpg > 31)
```

You can of course allow the NSE function to take character input as well but I’d advise against this — strongly. Don’t mix SE and NSE, there’s no advantage to be had, and it sows confusion (and potentially bugs, since you’re mixing domains).

That said, the following of course works:

```
subset2 <- function(df, condition) {
    if (is.character(substitute(condition)))
        subset2_(df, condition)
    else
        subset2_(df, lazy(condition))
}
```

If you want to allow NSE and SE in the same function for backwards compatibility reasons, I suggest phasing out the SE version in a future version, and adding a deprecation warning for now. To add the deprecation warning:

```
subset2 <- function(df, condition) {
    if (is.character(substitute(condition))) {
        msg = sprintf(paste0('Calling %s with a quoted expression is',
                             ' deprecated. Pass an unquoted expression',
                             ' instead, or use %s.'),
                      sQuote('subset2'), sQuote('subset2_'))
        .Deprecated(msg = msg)
        subset2_(df, condition)
    }
    else
        subset2_(df, lazy(condition))
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. So what would you suggest to make the transition to NSE and keep the backwards compatibility?

Comment: @Marti Ah, backwards compatibility is a very good argument. The standard solution for this is to publish a major revision in which the old behaviour is deprecated. In the *next* major revision after that, the old behaviour is removed, breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: I think that´s the way to go then. if I use the is.character on a non-quoted expression it throws an error though.  `Error in subset2(mtcars, mpg > 31) : object 'mpg' not found`