# Turn character into corresponding quosure

Tags: r

I've been practicing using the nonstandard evaluation (NSE) ideas on [this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html). Now I'm wondering how I can write functions that allow for either standard or non-standard evaluation in the way that dplyr functions work.

If I had this example:

```
f = function(df, col){
  col = enquo(col)
  print(col)
  df %>% 
    summarize(m = mean(!!col))
}

d = tibble(a = 1:3)
f(d, a)
```

I'm able to work with unquoted `a`. but calling `f(d, 'a')` gives a different quosure within the execution environment of f which causes the summarize to fail. Is there an easy way I can turn the argument `a` into a quosure in the case that the user supplies a character?

Thanks!

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33214278/5325862